# sorting strings out of 2d array into three seperate txt files? in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, filereader, filewriter

I am trying to sort files we read from one big txt and put them into three other txt files based on their first word into three categories... The three categories are Student, teacher, and staff. I am just stuck at this point and am not sure how to proceed. I have attached the code I have so far as well as the txt file. This code is c++

```
16
4 Staff Jean Arp 2000
4 Staff Edgar Degas 1988
7 Student Francis Bacon 2001 MA240 CS222 CS228
5 Student Salvador Dali 1998 CS255
6 Professor Marcel Duchamp 2015 CS302 CS297
4 Staff Andy Warhol 2016
8 Student Man Ray 2008 MA240 CS101 CS201 CS120
4 Staff Rene Magritte 2011
4 Student Franz Kline 1988
4 Student Wassily Kandinsky 2002
4 Staff Lucian Freud 1994
6 Professor Jackson Pollock 1977 CS370 CS470
8 Professor Mark Rothko 1978 CS370 CS470 CS480 CS422
4 Student Egon Schiele 1981
5 Student Diego Rivera 1975 CS422
7 Professor Francis Picabia 2014 CS365 CS326 MA240
```

---

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string filename;
    cout << "What is the name of the file?";
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open(filename);
    int rows;
    readFile >> rows;
    cout << rows;
    string **table = nullptr;
    table = new string*[rows];
    vector<int> vector;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        int item;
        readFile >> item;
        vector.push_back(item);
        table[i] = new string[item];
        for (int j = 0; j < item; j++)
        {
            readFile >> table[i][j];
        }
    }
    ofstream toStudent;
    toStudent.open("Student.txt");
    ofstream toStaff;
    toStaff.open("Staff.txt");
    ofstream toProfessor;
    toProfessor.open("Professor.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        if (table[i][0] == "Student")
        {
            //this is where I want to send the info to the files
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry, the txt files goes line by line and the number before each person shows how many elements follow in that row and there are 16 lines of txt after the number 16

Comment: `string **table` -> `vector<vector<string>> table`. It will help make the code clearer

Comment: strongly recommend against reusing an identifier like you do in `vector<int> vector;` Now that `vector` is a variable, you've made it tricky to make another `vector`.

Comment: What are you trying to sort?

Comment: You can do this all in one shot create your three output files. In a loop with the input file use getline() and check the first word. If the first word is == "Staff", then store the next 3 strings in the staff output file. same for the others but storing X next strings in their own corresponding output file.

Answer (score 3):

You are making it so complicated. No need for storing data if you can manipulate them on the fly. If you are trying to extract Students' data and store them in independent file, this is also the case for staff and professor, then follow the following logic

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename;
    cout << "What is the name of the file?";
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open(filename);
    int rows;
    readFile >> rows;
    cout << rows << endl;

    //-----------------------------------
    ofstream toStudent("Student.txt"), toStaff("Staff.txt"), toProfessor("Professor.txt");

    int dummy;
    string word, line;

    while ( std::getline(readFile, line) ){
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> dummy >> word;
        if ( word == "Student")
            toStudent << line << endl;
        else if ( word == "Staff" )
            toStaff << line << endl;
        else if ( word == "Professor" )
            toProfessor << line << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You didn't mention any thing regarding what you're trying to sort. Nonetheless, now you have the data for each category. It is easily to sort them.